# Why is unit type a member of Enum typeclass?

Tags: haskell

[LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses) says:

> `Enum` members are sequentially ordered types — they can be enumerated. The main advantage of the `Enum` typeclass is that we can use its types in list ranges. They also have defined successors and predecessors, which you can get with the `succ` and `pred` functions. Types in this class: `()`, `Bool`, `Char`, `Ordering`, `Int`, `Integer`, `Float` and `Double`.

Why is `()` a member of this typeclass? While it supports all the required functionality, it doesn't seem useful, in the sense that `succ` and `pred` will always fail, and using it in a list range would yield just `()` itself.

Comment: It's also `Bounded`, so `[minBound..maxBound]` works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The unofficial policy for these kinds of things is "make it an instance unless it can't be (in a law-abiding way)". This policy has caused some surprises in the past (the `Foldable`/`Traversable` instances for tuples spring to mind), but for the most part is a positive one. It is common to come across some function that you'd like to use that's polymorphic over a variety of classes, and be delighted to find that it works for the concrete type you happen to need in your current code because your concrete type has the appropriate instances in place.

Comment: I don't think that is the policy, official or otherwise (I certainly wouldn't agree with it). Else we'd also have `instance Monoid Int where {mempty = 0; mappend = (+)}`. I'd rather say the policy is, “make it an instance if there is exactly one law-abiding, non-pathological way to do it”. The “non-pathological” bit is of course a bit vague, but in case of `Enum ()` it's utterly obvious what the instance must do.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Thanks for the nuance; I agree that's an important part of the policy.

Comment: To expand on the `Foldable`/`Traversable` point, consider this code: `maximum (1,0)`. This looks like it should obviously be `1`, but it is actually `0` because the instance for `Foldable` for tuples considers the second element to be the thing it is "folding over," as in `foldMap f (_, y) = f y`.